# Building a visual diagnostic device

Tags: led, resistors

I am looking to build a device that will allow me to visually witness an I/O logic bus in real time. I have already built wiring harness "extensions" to facilitate access to the pins of the individual logic boards where I am trying to monitor.

The system uses old 44-pin edge connectors with removable logic boards that have fairly quick inputs and outputs taking place on the pins. I very simply would like to see an LED light up anytime there is 5 V on one of those 44 pins, so that I can ensure the board is recieving and/or sending the right signal, or see if the board is bad.

I want to do this without causing any increased load on the power supply that feeds these boards. My original plan was to use an array of LEDs tapped into the wiring harness for the respective pins that I am monitoring, but adding 44 LEDs and resistors is not a load I want to apply to these boards.

If I provide an external power supply, is there a way I can fully isolate my diagnostic LEDs from the logic voltages on the board?

To answer Johnathanjo - the speeds of the inputs and outputs vary by about 1/2 second to 4 or 5 seconds, whereas some are on indefinitely as long as specified switches are made up outside of the controller. Because I don't know the threshold load of the logic system, the less the better. 1mA would be ideal, but I could probably do 2 or 3 mA per pin without causing any unusualities.

DanMcB - I don't want the leds to latch, I only want them to be high as long as the inputs are present.

Comment: In engineering, always use numbers because one person's quick is another person's slow.  _"fairly quick inputs and outputs"_ **How quick?** 1ms, 1us, 1ns, 1ps?    And there are almost no absolutes: _"without causing any increased load"_ **How much load?** 1mA, 1uA?

Comment: do you want the LEDs to be latching (i.e remain on after an input goes high then low again) or instantaneous (only stay high while the signal is high)?

Comment: @jonathanjo my favourite example: the power company calls 240 volts "low voltage" and 48 volts "extra-low voltage". Their version of "medium voltage" is 11000 volts and "high voltage" is something like 330000 volts. For anyone on this website, 48 volts is pretty high and 240 is definitely high; medium is 12 volts or 5 volts, and low is 3.3 volts or 1.2 volts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These signals (at 500 ms or more) are easily slow enough that you don't need any latches.

**If you can afford 1 mA**

Find some very high efficiency LEDs and find out how low the current will still have them bright enough for your application.  You'll easily find some which are perfectly bright at 1 mA.

This is likely to be your simplest solution.

**If you can't even afford 1 mA**

Then you use some kind of buffer, perhaps a 74ALS04 which has an input current I<sub>IH</sub> max of 0.1 mA.  Or, as suggested in comments, "a CMOS input buffer with even higher input impedance? They are available with TTL compatible levels and even Schmitt trigger inputs." (Thanks @justme)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq9d6H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why an ALS, why not simply a CMOS input buffer with even higher input impedance? They are available with TTL compatible levels and even Schmitt trigger inputs.

Comment: @justme indeed of course there are lots which might be better in various ways.  edited.